# Custom accordion script in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do an accordion-style scrolling down and up, but when I click on "Header 1" (for example), it scrolls down, then back up. I need to have it so that it scrolls down, and only scrolls back up when I click it again (or when I click on a different header). Also, when my page loads, all of the headers are scrolled down, which I don't want. What can I do to fix this?

```
<style>
   .accord-content { display: none; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {
            if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
                $(this).next("div").slideUp("slow");
            } else {
                $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("slow");
                $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accord-header">Header 1</div>
  <div class="accord-content">Link 1</div>
  <div class="accord-header">Header 2</div>
  <div class="accord-content">Link 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please spend more time writing your question. There are numerous spelling and formatting errors in your post. If you can't be bothered to take a few minutes to review what you yourself wrote, why should I be bothered to take a few minutes to figure out what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly referencing your accord-content class in your CSS. Remove the '#'

```
.accord-content { display: none; }
```

Not sure I understand the rest of the problem, everything else seems to be working as you describe, unless I am misunderstanding the behavior you want.

Codepen example: http://cdpn.io/FeKyz

Comment: ok i see when i removed the "#" the second problem has been fixed but still i have the first problem : when i click on a header it scrolls up and down fast , i need it to scroll down and stop until i click again

Comment: @user2690826 with your code, it should not do that, do you have the script included twice?

Comment: thaaaaaaaanks bro , it worked out , i included it in the structure (for) haha ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two different function for the two different actions and then use bind and unbind.

```
function slideAccordianDown() {
    $(this).next("div").slideDown("slow");
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).bind("click", slideAccordianUp);
};

function slideAccordianUp() {
    $(this).next("div").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).bind("click", slideAccordianDown);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion .accord-header").click(slideAccordianDown);
});
```

Doing this will remove the function to slide down and stop it and then bind the functinon to slide it back up.